# What does the ? and : mean in these one line return statements?

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out what the ? and : mean in this one line return statement.

```
return input && input.length ? [input.filter(p => p > 0).length, input.filter(n => n < 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)] : [];
```

Comment: Ternary operator. Google it.

Comment: "In computer science, a ternary operator is an operator that takes three arguments." It's probably better to Google conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

This is a ternary if statement, I'd use parenthesis for organization sake, but it works like this:

[condition] ? [returns if condition is true] : [returns if condition is false]

Comment: In his case the condition is wether `input` is defined and has the property `length`.

Answer (score 0):

Return a ? a : b;

Means if a return a else return b!

Answer (score 0):

It means that if the condition before `?` is true then use the first part before `:` else use the second part.

In your case it means that if input is not null and has value, then return the filtered one otherwise return an empty array.

Comment: In the OP it will return an array of `[a, b]` where *a* is the number of elements greater than zero and *b* is their sum, or `[]` (empty array).